# Customize Search Form Block Text

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, search

I'm attempting to customize the search form block. I'd like to be able to change the search submit button, by either changing the text, or turning it into an icon and other various changes.

I assumed I'd be able to make these changes within a template, but the default block--search-form-block.html.twig only contains

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'block',
    'block-search',
    'container-inline',
  ]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if label %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {% block content %}
    {{ content }}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

I don't see anyway I can change anything such as the submit text. Is there any way to make direct changes to the search form block?

Comment: Is there a way to perform those actions within the theme file instead of creating a custom module for it?

Comment: Yes, you can put the form alter hook in `mytheme.theme`

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
#search-block-form input[type="submit"] {
background-color: white;
padding: 15px 25px;
color: black;
border-radius: 0px;
border: 1px grey dotted;
background-image: url(http://cashbin.win/sites/default/files/favicon.ico);
background-size: 30px 30px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

This is an example obviously replace the image and/or border, color, background, position, and padding options.

Add this into you /sites/all/themes/**CURRENT_THEME**/css/style.css

Hope this helps, God Bless!

Comment: This doesn't change the submit text and is oddly specific CSS without knowing the theme.

Comment: @Kevin matt hasn't answered yet but to someone who actually needs help they will be thankful for specifics I think.  I just decided to show what css options were available to him. He could change the setting and/or remove any.